# UseObjectDisposedExceptionRule : A method of an IDisposable type does not throw System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, properties

I have a page in MVP model. The properties in my view interface are implemented in the code behind ie .aspx.cs file. In most of the properties implemented in code behind , my code monitoring tool shows warning like:

UseObjectDisposedExceptionRule  : A method of an IDisposable type does not throw System.ObjectDisposedException.

The exception is shown in the setter ie,

```
    public bool IsOkToPtoceed
    {
    get
    {
     return _isOkToProceed;
    }
    set
    {
    /// warning is displayed in this line
    _isOkToProceed=value;
    }
    }
```

How am I supposed to handle the warning? Is it simply by using try catch block while setting value?

Answer (score 1):

It is a guideline to prevent use-after-dispose.

```
set
{
   /// warning is displayed in this line
   if (this.IsDisposed)
       throw new ObjectDisposedException("<classname>");

   _isOkToProceed=value;
}
```

Comment: The property I am using is setting the local private variables. No web controls has been used. In this case , how do I check if the object has been disposed or not? What is the namespace where IsDisposed is defined?

Comment: `IsDisposed` should be defined in the class, maybe as `_isDisposed` or something. Implementations vary. But it's safe to just turn off or ignore that warning.

Answer (score 1):

[Your tool tells you what you should do:](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/blob/master/gendarme/rules/Gendarme.Rules.Exceptions/UseObjectDisposedExceptionRule.cs#L115)

> Throw ObjectDisposedException if the object has been disposed.

```
public void Dispose ()
{
    if (!disposed) {
        // Implement the details of your dispose method here.
        disposed = true;
    }
}

private bool disposed;

public bool IsOkToPtoceed
{
    get
    {
        return _isOkToProceed;
    }
    set
    {
        if (disposed) {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException (GetType ().Name);
        }
        _isOkToProceed=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I check if the object has been disposed or not with minimal code? Any ideas?

Comment: @Neerajan I've added sample code, from the documentation available at the linked page.

Comment: what is writer in the current context?

Comment: I am getting this warning in more that 25 properties(in the setters), wont it create any problem to use a commom private bool disposed variable?

Comment: @Neerajan I assume that your class has the `IDisposable` interface specified? If so, then you must have good reason to do so (and thus also know how to implement this properly)? If not, then there's something wrong with your code monitoring tool.

Comment: Yes, there is association with the IDisposable interface. I have never encountered such exceptions in any of the lines but I am getting warning in the tool.